# Flask web app on Cloud Run - google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError:

Tags: python, grpc, google-cloud-run

I'm hosting a Flask web app on Cloud Run. I'm also using Secret Manager to store Service Account keys. (I previously downloaded a JSON file with the keys)

In my code, I'm accessing the payload then using `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = payload` to authenticate. When I deploy the app and try to visit the page, I get an Internal Service Error. Reviewing the logs, I see:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 121, in load_credentials_from_file
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: File {"
```

I can access the secret through `gcloud` just fine with: `gcloud secrets versions access 1 --secret="<secret_id>"` while acting as the Service Account.

Here is my Python code:

```
# Grabbing keys from Secret Manager
def access_secret_version():

    # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    name = "projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/1"

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})

    payload = response.payload.data.decode("UTF-8")
    return payload

@app.route('/page/page_two')
def some_random_func():

    # New way
    payload = access_secret_version() # <---- calling the payload
   
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = payload


    # Old way
    os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "service-account-keys.json"
```

I'm not technically accessing a JSON file like I was before. The `payload` variable is storing entire key. Is this why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect.

When you run on a Google compute service like Cloud Run, the code runs under the identity of the compute service.

In this case, by default, Cloud Run uses the Compute Engine default service account but, it's good practice to create a Service Account for your service and specify it when you deploy it to Cloud Run (see [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts)).

This mechanism is one of the "legs" of Application Default Credentials when your code is running on Google Cloud, you **don't** specify the environment variable (you also don't need to create a key) and Cloud Run service acquires the credentials from the Metadata service:

```py
import google.auth

credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
```

See [`google.auth` package](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-auth/latest/reference/google.auth.html)

It is bad practice to define|set an environment variable within code. By their nature, environment variables should be provided by the environment. Doing this with `APPLICATION_DEFAULT_CREDENTIALS` means that your code always sets this value when it should only do this when the code is running off Google Cloud.

For completeness, if you need to create `Credentials` from a JSON string rather than from a file contain a JSON string, you can use `from_service_account_info` (see [`google.oauth2.service_account`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/master/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html))

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I didn't specify in my post but I'm accessing a BigQuery table from my Cloud Run `main.py` file which is why I needed the credentials in the first place. Sounds like you are saying that I don't need the keys at all and just need to deploy the code as a service account that has the `BigQuery Admin` role **OR** I can add that `BigQuery Admin` role to the default compute engine service account?

Comment: Yes, you were right. Just tested. Thank you.

Comment: That's correct. Sorry for the late reply. The service account can be given whatever I AM roles needed to access services.